# Apache Nifi: How to convert string (text/plain) to JSON type using Nifi processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

Please guide me the right component for converting string to json 
using appropriate Nifi processor component.

Input is a string of content type text/plain

```
{ productName : "tv", locationName: " chennai"}
```

Output of EvaluateJsonPath is still the same as I am unable to evaluate json property based on json path due to wrong content type sent as input.

```
{ 
 productName : "tv",
 locationName: " chennai"
}
```

Note: Tried SplitText, AttirtubesToJson processors not able to achieve desired conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the input data is not valid JSON. I recreated this flow locally and the error from `EvaluateJsonPath` is

```
2017-08-22 10:20:21,079 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.p.standard.EvaluateJsonPath EvaluateJsonPath[id=0aec27af-015e-1000-fac5-4e0f455a10fe] FlowFile StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=b903eeb0-8985-4517-910f-5e3bbbccb8dc,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1503421928125-1, container=default, section=1], offset=376, length=47],offset=0,name=91708717370829,size=47] did not have valid JSON content.
```

Which condenses to *[flowfile] did not have valid JSON content*. The processor uses a strict validator and the input you're providing is not valid JSON. You'll need to use text manipulation or regexes to update this content to the following:

```
{"productName":"tv", "locationName":"chennai"}
```

Once you have accomplished this (via `ReplaceText`, etc.), the `EvaluateJsonPath` processor will work properly.

Also, to be clear, `EvaluateJsonPath` is designed to execute JSONPath expressions to extract JSON values to flowfile attributes. It is not designed to manipulate arbitrary text into JSON format.

**Update**

There is no universal process to convert arbitrary data to JSON. Given the specific input you provided, the following values for `ReplaceText` will convert this to valid JSON:

- Search Value: `(?<!\")(\w+)(?=[\s:])`
- Replacement Value: `"$1"`
- Replacement Strategy: `Regex Replace`
- Evaluation Mode: `Entire text`

If you get incoming data that is invalid in some other way, you'll have to modify this process. You may be interested in something like [JSONLint](https://github.com/circlecell/jsonlint.com) to validate and format your incoming data.

Comment: Andy, Thanks for the answer, yes I understand it is not correct format How do I convert my incoming string to JSON . Do we have any component that takes care of it ? or how do I do it in ReplaceText , could you please post sample of Replace Text that would be great.

Comment: Andy, Thanks for your help, I will try this out. We have lot of complex processors in place for nifi but something like  ConvertStringToJson will definitely help us a lot to do simple process instead of writing regex patterns etc. Anyways thanks for the advice.